# Loading dataframe from Azure Databricks into Azure Queue Storage

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-eventgrid, azure-queues

We do have a use case where we are building some dataframe in batch load and would like to load into Azure queue so that it can be read by a REST API later.

Instead calling the API to post data we would like to save it in some message queue that can be read by the REST API to process further.

The dataframe contain 20k records with schema like(example):
[image]

Present code snippet:

```
df=final_df.withColumn("status_code",post_udf('ColA','ColB','ColC','ColD'))
```

The udf function post the data to API and return the status code.

I would like to save above transformed dataframe into azure message queue/azure event grid or any other service, from where the API can access it.

Comment: Please edit to show relevant work (code, sample data, expected vs actual behavior, etc). As written, it's unclear what you've done or what you're having issues with. FYI you can't just place a data frame into queue messages; you have to do your own transform and output (and that's the type of thing you should be sharing here)

Comment: @DavidMakogon I did not get that point!! the dataframe is already transformed and I want to keep it any message queue/azure event grid so that API can read it later.

Comment: fyi - not sure why you re-added [tag:azure-eventgrid] - as written, this question is not about event grid specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Azure Functions** to get data from azure queue.
Follow below steps,

First, run below code for sending data into queue.

```
import os
import json
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient, QueueClient, QueueMessage

json_data = df.toJSON().collect()
queue_name = "Your queue name(tst in my case)"
connection_string = "Your connection string"
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, queue_name)
for data in json_data:
    queue_client.send_message(data)
```

Below is the data i have.

[image]

This code sends each row of dataframe to queue.
Before sending data, it is converted to Json format and sends it.

Below is the result of my data in queue,
[image]

Here, you can see each row is updated.

Next, you need to create an azure function.
[image]

Go to **Function App** and click on create.
After creating function app, let's deploy function in visual code.

Open visual code, go to extensions and search for `Azure Function` and install it.
You will get azure symbol at bottom left as below.
[image]

Go to azure tab, there click on the option shown below to create function.

[image]

which prompts to select type of trigger. Select `HTTP Trigger` then name of the function and authorization level as `anonymous`.

After creating the function, you will get a `__init__.py`and project structure as below.

[image]

Here, you can see `requirements.txt` there add the following package in it.
`azure-storage-queue`

[image]

By default, the code will be as below in `**init**.py.

[image]

Replace that code with the below code.

```
import  logging
import azure.functions as  func
import  json
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient, QueueClient, QueueMessage

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    queue_name = "Your queue name(tst in my case)"
    connection_string = "Your connection string"
    queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, queue_name)
    retrieved_message = queue_client.receive_messages()
    res = []
    
    for  i  in  retrieved_message:
        res.append(json.loads(i.content))
        
    res = json.dumps(res)
    logging.info(res)
    return  func.HttpResponse(f"Data : {res}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

Next give your queue name and connection string.

[image: upload]

After updating the code, click on the option shown in image to deploy the function. Again, it prompts to select `subscription id`,`resource group` and `azure function`  you created before in azure. Select them appropriately.

That starts the deployment.
After deployment, go to app function you created in azure, there you can find deployed functions under **Function tab**.

You will get details as below.
[image]

Copy the function URL and test it.
I tested using postman.
You can see the result here.

[image]